# Else/Elif statements

Tags: python

```
def alpha_check(string):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    counter = 0
    missing_letters = []
    for i in string:
        if i in alphabet and i in string:
            counter += 1
        elif i not in string:
            print("This code ran")
            missing_letters.append(i)
    if counter == 26:
        print("This string has all letters in the alphabet")
    else:
        print(str(missing_letters))

#Function test
alpha_check("abcdefghijklmnz")
```

I'm trying to write a function that either returns the fact that a string has all letters in the alphabet or returns what letters are missing in the word from the alphabet. My else if statements aren't running and I'm trying to understand why not.

I tried changing around the first if-statement, and adding print statements to see if the else/elif statements actually ran. The code seems sound to me and I am unable to detect what the issue with the else statements is.

Comment: You're putting each letter in `string` one by one as the argument and then you're checking if the letter is not in `string`? It doesn't make sense. Elif checks if the argument above is false and the argument after the keyword is true.

Comment: The `and i in string` portion of `if i in alphabet and i in string` will *always* be `True` because you're iterating over `string`, so it's unnecessary. Likewise, `elif i not in string` will *always* be `False` because you know that `i` is in the string since that's where `i` came from in the first place

Comment: The loop is `for i in string`, therefore `i` **must** be present in `string`, therefore `i not in string` **must** be false.

Answer (score 4):

For this loop:

```
for i in string
```

This condition will *always* be true:

```
if i in alphabet and i in string
```

Because `alphabet` has all letters and `string` has all values of `i` being used in the loop.

I suspect you meant to loop over `alphabet` instead, and check if `i` is in `string` (in which case the `elif` can also just be an `else`):

```
for i in alphabet:
    if i in string:
        counter += 1
    else:
        print("This code ran")
        missing_letters.append(i)
```

Comment: I understand now, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As an added note to [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77369826/15261315), your check if a string contains all of the letters in the alphabet can be made much simpler with a set intersection.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def alpha_check(string):
  alpha_set = set(ascii_lowercase)
  return len(alpha_set & set(string)) == len(alpha_set)
```

We can use sets to find the missing letters as well. The `^` does an exclusive or operation on the two sets, but this might return spaces or punctuation, so then intersecting it with the alphabet removes those.

Sets are not guaranteed to be in-order, so we then use `sorted` to get a sorted list of the missing letters.

```
>>> sorted(alpha_set) ^ set("hello world") & alpha_set)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

In fact, we could simply run this, and if it's an empty list, determine that the string contains all of the letters of the alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

If any of the condition is failed in `and` logical operator (if statement) it will execute elif. In the example you have shown, there is no such case that will make it false. Therefore it is not calling elif.

I've put in place a function here that will assist you in achieving the same objective and has enough lines to clarify the reasoning.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def alpha_check(string: str):
    string = string.lower()
    db = {ch: 0 for ch in ascii_lowercase}

    for ch in string:
        db[ch] += + 1    
    
    missing_chars = []
    for ch, occurrence in db.items():
        if occurrence == 0:
            missing_chars.append(ch)
        pass
    return missing_chars

print(alpha_check("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
print(alpha_check("acdefghijklmnopq"))
```

```
[]
['b', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you seek:

> a function that either returns the fact that a string has all letters in the alphabet or returns what letters are missing

You want to take the `set.difference()` between your two strings.

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase

def alpha_check(string):
  return sorted(set(ascii_lowercase).difference(string)) or True

print(alpha_check("the quick brown fox"))
print(alpha_check(ascii_lowercase))
```

That should give you:

```
['a', 'd', 'g', 'j', 'l', 'm', 'p', 's', 'v', 'y', 'z']
True
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution I have seen. @JonSG, kudos to you.